# JupyterHub Oracle InstantClient and cx_Oracle installation

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle, jupyterhub, instantclient

I installed JupyterHub using Docker container.

1. I created a new Anaconda Environment "cx_oracle_env", and installed package cx_Oracle in Terminal:

   ```
   # Creates a new Anaconda Environment called "cx_oracle_env" using Python 3.7 in silent mode
   conda create -n cx_oracle_env python=3.7 -y
   # >>>> Returns no warnings / errors

   # Activates the Anaconda Environment "cx_oracle_env"
   conda activate cx_oracle_env
   # >>>> Returns no warnings / errors

   # Mamba is a reimplementation of the conda package manager in C++.
   # - parallel downloading of repository data and package files using multi-threading
   # - libsolv for much faster dependency solving, a state of the art library used in the 
   #   RPM package     manager of Red Hat, Fedora and OpenSUSE
   # - core parts of mamba are implemented in C++ for maximum efficiency
   # At the same time, mamba utilize the same command line parser, package installation and 
   # deinstallation code and transaction verification routines as conda to stay as compatible as 
   # possible.
   #
   conda install mamba -n base -c conda-forge -y
   # >>>> Returns no warnings / errors

   # Installs ipykernel in currently active Anaconda Environment
   mamba install ipykernel -y
   # >>>> Returns no warnings / errors

   # Installs cx_Oracle
   python -m pip install cx_Oracle --upgrade
   # >>>> Returns no warnings / errors

   # Binds ipykernel "cx_oracle_env" to Anaconda Environment "cx_oracle_env"
   python -m ipykernel install --user --name cx_oracle_env --display-name="cx_oracle_env"
   # >>>> Returns no warnings / errors
   ```
2. I downloaded the ORACLE InstantClient **instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.1.0.0.0.zip** from https://www.oracle.com/uk/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html to my local computer, and uploaded the zip file to my JupyterHub working directory.
3. I opened a new Jupyter Notebook by selecting "cx_oracle_env" in section Notebook of the Launcher panel.
4. In Jupyter Notebook, I decompressed the file instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.1.0.0.0.zip using following command:

   ```
   from shutil import unpack_archive
   # Decompress ZIP-file to working directory (/home/jovyan/instantclient_21_1/)
   unpack_archive('instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.1.0.0.0.zip', '')
   >>>> Returns no warnings / errors
   ```
5. Check if path exists:

   ```
   import os.path
   from os import path
   path.exists("/home/jovyan/instantclient_21_1")
   # >>>> Returns True
   ```
6. Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

   ```
   import os
   os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = "/home/jovyan/instantclient_21_1"
   !echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   # >>>> Returns /home/jovyan/instantclient_21_1
   ```
7. Set ORACLE_HOME:

   ```
   os.environ["ORACLE_HOME"] = "/home/jovyan/instantclient_21_1"
   !echo $ORACLE_HOME
   # >>>> Returns /home/jovyan/instantclient_21_1
   ```
8. Install libaio:

   ```
   !mamba install libaio -y
   # >>>> Returns no warnings / errors
   ```
9. Import cx_Oracle:

   ```
   import cx_Oracle
   # >>>> Returns no warnings / errors
   ```
10. After Calling init_oracle_client, I get following error:

    ```
    cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=r"/home/jovyan/instantclient_21_1")
    ```

[image]

What am I missing?

PS: Unfortunately I don't have sudo permissions here in JupyterHub Terminal ...
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem finally by creating a new JupyterHub environment by customizing the Dockerfile from https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/blob/master/minimal-notebook/Dockerfile, and embedded it as new "Minimal Oracle environment" in JupyterHub.

The custom Dockerfile has following content (I only added the "cx_Oracle installation begin/end" part):

```
# Copyright (c) Jupyter Development Team.
# Distributed under the terms of the Modified BSD License.
ARG BASE_CONTAINER=jupyter/base-notebook
FROM $BASE_CONTAINER

LABEL maintainer="Jupyter Project <jupyter@googlegroups.com>"

USER root

# Install all OS dependencies for fully functional notebook server
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    vim-tiny \
    git \
    inkscape \
    libsm6 \
    libxext-dev \
    libxrender1 \
    lmodern \
    netcat \
    # ---- nbconvert dependencies ----
    texlive-xetex \
    texlive-fonts-recommended \
    texlive-plain-generic \
    # ----
    tzdata \
    unzip \
    nano-tiny \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# cx_Oracle installation begin
WORKDIR /opt/oracle
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libaio1 wget
RUN wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip && \
    unzip instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip && rm -f instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip && \
    cd /opt/oracle/instantclient* && rm -f *jdbc* *occi* *mysql* *README *jar uidrvci genezi adrci && \
    echo /opt/oracle/instantclient* > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf && ldconfig
RUN python -m pip install cx_Oracle
WORKDIR $HOME
# cx_Oracle installation end

# Create alternative for nano -> nano-tiny
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/nano nano /bin/nano-tiny 10

# Switch back to jovyan to avoid accidental container runs as root
USER $NB_UID
```

After building the custom Dockerfile locally, and embedding it into the Kubernetes Cluster as "Minimal Oracle environment", I started a new Jupyter Notebook in the newly created JupyterHub environment, and tested the ORACLE connect as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` *must* be set prior to starting the process, so changing it in your Python script won't work.

In addition, due to limitations in how the instant client is currently built, `cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client()` cannot be used on Linux without also previously setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` outside of the process. Hopefully that limitation will be removed soon, but in the meantime, that's what you have to do. You can also use `ld.so.conf` configuration to make the installation work for your entire machine, in which case setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is no longer needed.

Comment: Also, don't set ORACLE_HOME when using Instant Client.  For more info, refer to the [Instant Client installation instructions](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html#ic_x64_inst) which are at the bottom of the download page.  For info on cx_Oracle initialization see https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html